# Some text are having black box or a black mark over certain letters in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome, system-installation, text-processing, gnome-panel

I am always having text glitches or we can say a type of black box over some of the alphabets, and this is occurring more frequently these days. The normal texts which I have on the documents and text inside an applications are working fine and there is no problem with that, but in the notification panel and name of the icons are having those type of black box or black mark on the text. One in ten boot ups the text will be fine but rest 9 will be having a text glitch. I have attached the pics you can see that.

[image: On the drop down arrow]
[image: On the calendar]
[image: Application options]

[image: Notification bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and now the texts are looking fine.The problem was with the fonts.

So I installed the **gnome-tweaks-tool**.

Run this command - `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

After performing that command, go to the **search** **bar** in the menu and search for tweaks.

Select the font section and change to any other font you like.
That's it, those boxes will be gone now.

:)
XPRX77